# Why is predicted rainfall by LSTM coming negative for some data points?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, training, rnn

I have used supervised learning with LSTM network using tanh activation function and 0.1 dropout for time series prediction.my loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam'. The predicted time series is shown below where x axis shows future months and y axis shows rainfall in mm.Orange line is predicted and blue line is actual. Some points are being predicted below 0 (negative) even though training dataset has all points having values >=0. My training dataset is of 64 years (all positive data)  and I am predicting for 12 years (144 data points shown) [image: Rainfall prediction]

Model code using ReLU activation:

```
model = Sequential()
# LSTM model
model.add(LSTM(128, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, look_back, 1),activation='relu', stateful=True, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.1)) #for better regularization
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
```

Comment: Because your model is not aware of the non-negative constraint. You could try  using a non-negative transformation like $\exp$ or $\max(x,0)$. Welcome to the site.

Comment: Emre, that is an answer not a comment.

Comment: So if I use relu activation function, will this problem get solved?

Answer (score 5):

Currently your model is not restricted from guessing any number. In this case, you may want to use something like a ReLU activation function to restrict your output domain.

The ReLU activation needs to be added to the last layer of your model. If you add it to an intermediate layer but not the last layer then your model can still output negative numbers, e.g. in the case of the last layer having a negative weight.

Note this is not really a new idea. There are strong similarities between logistic regression and what we’re doing here. In both cases we want to limit the possible guesses, in your case to non-negative numbers and in logistic regression‘s case to [0, 1].

Comment: Thanks.  ReLU should work then, I will try and let you know.

Comment: I tried using ReLU but in that case while training, after some epochs, the loss is all of a sudden going to NA. I am not sure why this is happening?

Comment: Are you doing division anywhere in your model?

Comment: If you share your architecture it will be easier to help.

Comment: model = Sequential()
    #LSTM model
    model.add(LSTM(128,
                   batch_input_shape=(batch_size, look_back, 1),activation='relu',
                   stateful=True,
                   return_sequences=False))  
    model.add(Dropout(0.1)) #for better regularization
    model.add(Dense(1))  
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

Comment: Thank you. Did anything else change between the model without NA and with NA values? Are you sure you have no NA values in your inputs?

Comment: Also you didn’t seem to add ReLU to the layer where it matters (last Dense).

Comment: I do not have any NA values in my input data series....its official rainfall data for a location collected by an authorised public agency.  Regarding ReLU, since I have already have that as my activation function in middle layer, why do I need to add it to the last Dense layer ?

Comment: I've updated my answer to try and explain why ReLU needs to be in the last layer. Essentially, what if your Dense layer has a negative weight? You would estimate a negative number. Also, arguments by authority that your data does not contain NA values are less convincing than just asserting that via code.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions. I will try training using ReLU in the last layer as well. Hopefully this time I don't get the loss to go to NA nor the output as negative.

Comment: I am still getting loss:nan after say, about 75% of training time. Tried with ReLU in the middle layer and in last layer as you suggested. Something is wrong somewhere it seems.

Comment: Did you ever check if you have NaN values in your inputs? Also it's really hard to diagnose those kinds of problems without comprehensive code. Maybe you should ask another question?